# what is version of an assembly?

Tags: .net, versioning

i am confuse with what is version of an assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET, each assembly has a version number as part of its identity.

This version information for each assembly is stored within the assembly manifest along with  various other meta-data regarding the assembly like name, strong name, types exposed, types referenced etc

As such, two assemblies that differ by version number are considered by the runtime to be completely different assemblies.

This version number is physically represented as a four-part string with the following format:

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>
```

eg:- abc.dll v1.1.100.200

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: And this is separate from the file and informational (or product) versions part of the Version Resource of any Win32 executable.